# How to minimize the large number of import statement in an angular module?

Tags: angular, es6-class, angular-module

In my angular module, I have 50 lines of `import` statements to import those classes and use in the declarations sections of the `@NgModule`.

In C++, there is a `include` file concept where you can put all the classes in a include file and use that file. How can I make my module more readable by hiding the details of the importing components?

This is how my `@NgModule` module file starts:

[image]

Comment: You can create a file and add the imports statement there, Then import the single file in the module. Do you have any better solution apart from this?. If yes, share

Answer (score 3):

You can have another module right next to the feature module that imports all the classes and re-exports them to be consumed by the feature module.

FeatureImportsModule.ts:

```
import { ComponentA } from 'path/to/file'
import { ComponentB } from 'path/to/file'
...


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
    ....
    ],
  exports: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB,
    ...
  ]
})
export class FeatureImportsModule { }
```

FeatureModule.ts, this is the one that becomes "more readable":

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ FeatureImportsModule ]
export class FeatureModule { }
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem because you have to still declare the same number of components.

Comment: This is meant to make your primary module readable. Because this moves the imports to a secondary module right next to it, similar to an include file. Just like you have asked in the question. "How can I make my module more readable by hiding the details of the importing components". THIS HIDES IT BY MOVING THEM TO A SECONDARY MODULE. I don't know how to make this anymore simpler for you. Oh did you fail to realise that these are two seperate files?